# Spring Batch: Calculating sum of a field per file in MultiResourceItemWriter

Tags: java, spring-batch

I need to calculate the sum of a specific field (amount) per file with MultiResourceItemWriter to write it in the footer. Passing all the records to the footer callback is not an option since we are processing a lot of data, and it costs memory.

Before implementing MultiResourceItemWriter, I used the beforeWrite and afterWrite methods by implementing the ItemWriterListener to compute the sum. But for some reason, the listener of the delegate writer was not called when we implemented MultiResourceItemWriter.

Is there any way we can calculate the sum per file? Is there a way to execute some code before and after writing to each file?